# Anki and AnkiDroid: Importing JSON from collection.media with javascript

Tags: anki

I want to import files from `collection.media` that are not sound, image, or video. For example I'd like to import a JSON file.

I put the file `_script.jquery-3.3.1.min.js` and `_data.json` in my `collection.media` folder.

On Anki Desktop (Ubuntu), the following works:

```
<script src="_script.jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$.getJSON('_data.json', function(data) {
    // succeeds on Anki Desktop, fails on AnkiDroid
});
</script>
```

(Note on Anki Desktop 2.0.47 I am using the JS Booster plugin).

On AnkiDroid, the situation is different. JQuery loads just fine in the script tag. However, `$.getJSON` fails to find the `_data.json` file.

I'd like to use `_data.json` on many cards/notes.

How can I import non-media, non-js files from `collection.media` in javascript, in a way that works both in Anki Desktop and AnkiDroid?

Answer (score 1):

I have found some working answer for this.
To get character data in AnkiDroid card templates. (OFFLINE)

As we can access js and image file using this

```js
<script src="some-js-file.js"></script>
<img src="some-image.png"></img>
```

To access `json`
I have tried same steps but getting `CORS` error so I used next steps.

```js
<!-- It will give CORS error -->
<script src="我.json" type="application/json"></script>
```

With example,
To access `我.json` file

1. Copy contents of `我.json` into a javascript file `我.js`, with any variable name,

```js
var char_data = {"strokes":["M 350 571 Q 3....}
```

2. Add following tag to access that js file

```js
<!--  Note : file type & name -->
<script src="我.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

3. Now also change code in `_hanzi-writer.min.js`

To change code, first beautify code using this https://beautifier.io, then make following change
a) Remove the link to load from internet
b) Change this `200 != r.status` and replace/add this

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(char_data))
```

( May be more good replacement can be done here )

[image: HanziWriter]

```js
....
....
// Note :  char_data variable come from 我.js file
r.overrideMimeType && r.overrideMimeType("application/json"), r.open("GET", "", !0), r.onerror = function(t) {
....
....
 4 === r.readyState && (200 != r.status ? i(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(char_data))) : 0 !== r.status && n && n(r))
....
....
```

4. So final script will be like this
   Front side of card

```js
{{Pinyin}}

<div id="character-target-div"></div>

<script src= "我.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var data = JSON.stringify(char_data);
console.log(data);
</script>

<script src="_hanzi-writer.min.js"></script>

<script>
var writer = HanziWriter.create('character-target-div', '我', {
  width: 150,
  height: 150,
  showCharacter: false,
  padding: 5
});
writer.quiz();
</script>
```

Above all the steps are for single file `我.js`

To access other character repeat the same.

For similar issues view my code

https://github.com/infinyte7/Anki-xiehanzi

https://github.com/infinyte7/hanzi-writer-data-in-javascript

Comment: This 写汉字 project is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is related to how AnkiDroid handles `collections.media` files. If so, this might be a bug. A really hackish workaround could be to rename the file to `.svg` so that AnkiDroid treats it as an image and lets it through.